# Bigquery rows to columns

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pivot, transpose

I have a table like below

**scores_table**

| id | item | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | ABC | 400 |
| 12345 | PQR | 650 |
| 12345 | XYZ | 350 |

I want to convert it to a single row and distribute the values across multiple columns.

| id | type1 | score1 | type2 | score2 | type3 | score3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | ABC | 400 | XYZ | 350 | PQR | 650 |

There are only 3 types and scores for every id. How do I achieve this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provied the data for the example in a code format so it can easily be read as a csv.

Comment: Or write it as a pandas dataframe so the example can be reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below query using **PIVOT**,

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) rn
    FROM sample_table
) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(item) type, ANY_VALUE(score) score FOR rn IN (1, 2, 3));
```

##### Query results

```
+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|  id   | type_1 | score_1 | type_2 | score_2 | type_3 | score_3 |
+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 12345 | XYZ    |     350 | PQR    |     650 | ABC    |     400 |
+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```